# Interval inside React useEffect - store it in a useRef Hook to preserve value overtime warning

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app, intervals, react-hooks

So I have this method:

```
useEffect(() => {
    //.. other logic here

    // Firefox doesn't support looping video, so we emulate it this way
    video.addEventListener(
      "ended",
      function() {
        video.play();
      },
      false
    );
  }, [videoWidth, videoHeight]);
```

Now it throws an error where it says:

```
Assignments to the 'interval' variable from inside React Hook useEffect will be lost after each render. To preserve the value over time, store it in a useRef Hook and keep the mutable value in the '.current' property. Otherwise, you can move this variable directly inside useEffect.
```

I am confused on what does this mean? especially this part: `To preserve the value over time, store it in a useRef Hook and keep the mutable value in the '.current' property`.

Comment: Can you put the whole code of your component, it would be great to help you to resolve the error.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The error is pointing you to the right direction. Use the `useRef` hook to reference the video element. Since the `handleVideo` function makes the dependencies of useEffect Hook change on every render we wrap the `handleVideo` definition into its own `useCallback()` Hook.

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useCallback } from "react";

function Video() {
  const videoRef = useRef(null);

  const handleVideo = useCallback(() => {
    videoRef.current.play()
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    const video = videoRef.current
    video.addEventListener('ended', handleVideo)

    return () => {
      video.removeEventListener('ended', handleVideo)
    }
  }, [handleVideo])



  return <video width="400" controls ref={videoRef} src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" />
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this way it will be work

```
const video = useRef(null);
const videoPlay = () => { //just hate stateFull Function
        video.current.play();
      }
useEffect(() => {
    //.. other logic here

    // Firefox doesn't support looping video, so we emulate it this way
    video.addEventListener(
      "ended",
      videoPlay,
      false
    );
    return video.removeEventListener("ended", videoPlay, true)
  }, [videoWidth, videoHeight, video]);
```

```
   <video ref={video}>
      <source src={src} type="video/mp4" />
   </video>
```

if put the code in [jsfiddle](http://%20https://jsfiddle.net/) or some whare like this we can help you more